# Change active state on scroll to viewport

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to make a single static website, which when an div child of  comes into viewport (precisely, when div element comes into the upper 50% of the viewport) changes the corresponding div's class in side-nav to "active". It should work scrolling down and up.

So far I've tried several solution from other threads on SO, none successful. I assume I've been approaching this wrong.

```js
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
  $("#vars-args").each(function() {
  if (elementInViewport2($(this))) {
    $(this).find("#div1a").addClass("active");
  }
});
});

function elementInViewport2(el) {
  var top = el.offsetTop;
  var left = el.offsetLeft;
  var width = el.offsetWidth;
  var height = el.offsetHeight;

  while (el.offsetParent) {
    el = el.offsetParent;
    top += el.offsetTop;
    left += el.offsetLeft;
  }

  return (
    top < (window.pageYOffset + window.innerHeight) &&
    left < (window.pageXOffset + window.innerWidth) &&
    (top + height) > window.pageYOffset &&
    (left + width) > window.pageXOffset
  );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div id="side-nav">
  <a href="" id="div1a">1</a>
  <a href="" id="div2a">2</a>
  <a href="" id="div3a">3</a>
  <a href="" id="div4a">4</a>
  <a href="" id="div5a">5</a>
  <a href="" id="div6a">6</a>
</div>
<div id="content">
  <div id="div1">
    <!--content-->
  </div>
  <div id="div2">
    <!--content-->
  </div>
  <div id="div3">
    <!--content-->
  </div>
  <div id="div4">
    <!--content-->
  </div>
  <div id="div5">
    <!--content-->
  </div>
  <div id="div6">
    <!--content-->
  </div>
</div>
```

Also note that content of each div inside  can be larger than the size of viewport.

I have been having problems getting the javascript to work. Also please note that the current JS is copied from some other thread.

Comment: you should use intersectionobserver for this, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API  Check the example down there which shows your problem exactly.

Comment: Did my answer solve what you were trying to achieve ?

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved using the IntersectionObserver as told by @cloned in the comments: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API

To achieve this, you need a **callback** function passed as a parameter which is executed once `isIntersecting` is *true*, an **option** object (below it sets the *threshold* at 50% of the element) and an **IntersectionObserver**.

The callback toggles the active class to the *a* element according to the entry's *id*.

At the end we loop through the *divs* and make our observer observe them.

```
const callback = (entries, observer) => {
entries.forEach(entry => {
  const navItem = document.querySelector('#' + entry.target.id + 'a');
    if (entry.isIntersecting) {
      console.log(navItem.getAttribute('id'));
      navItem.classList.add('active');
    } else {
      navItem.classList.remove('active');
    }
  });
};
const options = {
  threshold: 0.5
};
const observer = new IntersectionObserver(callback, options);
const container = document.getElementById('content');
const targetElements = container.querySelectorAll('div');


targetElements.forEach(element => {
 observer.observe(element);
});
```

Here is a *JSBin* to demonstrate it https://jsbin.com/riyuhediso/47/edit?html,js,console,output

**Note** that although it demonstrates its feasibility it's not been profiled for performance issues which can be significant so I don't vouch for it.

If you are using *Bootstrap* you can use the *ScrollSpy* lib https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/scrollspy/ and there is also *ScrollMagic* which is great http://scrollmagic.io/

Answer (score 1):

You need to filter out which element is inside the viewport with the help of `.getBoundingClientRect()` 
Checkout [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect)

and check if any content has it's top and bottom within the half of the viewport ( `window.innerHeight` )

I took help of filter function to find out the index of contents that is within the built in function and set the `.active` class of the corresponding anchor.

Have a look at the snippet:

```js
var direction = 0; // a variable to keep track of scrolled position;
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
  // check if window is scrolling up or down;
  if ($(window).scrollTop() > direction) { // if true, window scrolling scrolling down;
    $('#side-nav').find('a').removeClass('active'); // remove active class from all anchors
    $('#side-nav').find('a').eq(
      // .eq() selector helps to find elements with index number, and here we pass a filter to find the content that is within the viewport;
      $('#content').find('div').filter(function(index) {
        return this.getBoundingClientRect().y <= (window.innerHeight / 2) && this.getBoundingClientRect().y + this.getBoundingClientRect().height > window.innerHeight / 2;
      }).index()
    ).addClass('active');
    // update the current scroll position now;
    direction = $(window).scrollTop();

  } else { // if false, window scrolling scrolling up;
    $('#side-nav').find('a').removeClass('active'); // remove active class from all anchors
    $('#side-nav').find('a').eq(
      $('#content').find('div').filter(function(index) {
        return this.getBoundingClientRect().y < (window.innerHeight / 2) && this.getBoundingClientRect().y + this.getBoundingClientRect().height > window.innerHeight / 2;
      }).index()
    ).addClass('active');
    // update the current scroll position now;
    direction = $(window).scrollTop();
  }
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#side-nav {
  /* feel free to remove or change, only for testing */
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  padding: 15px;
}

#side-nav a {
  /* feel free to remove, only for testing */
  text-decoration: none;
  color: grey;
  margin-right: 5px;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#side-nav a.active {
  color: #000;
  /* sets color for the default active class */
}

#content div {
  min-height: 600px;
  background-color: #cecece;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="side-nav">
  <a href="" id="div1a" class='active'>1</a>
  <!-- set a default class assuming the first one will be in viewport while window loads -->
  <a href="" id="div2a">2</a>
  <a href="" id="div3a">3</a>
  <a href="" id="div4a">4</a>
  <a href="" id="div5a">5</a>
  <a href="" id="div6a">6</a>
</div>
<div id="content">
  <div id="div1">
    <p>One</p>
  </div>
  <div id="div2">
    <p>Two</p>
  </div>
  <div id="div3">
    <p>Three</p>
  </div>
  <div id="div4">
    <p>Four</p>
  </div>
  <div id="div5">
    <p>Five</p>
  </div>
  <div id="div6">
    <p>Six</p>
  </div>
</div>
```